# How to mock a function to return a dummy value in scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mockito, scalatest

```
    object ReadUtils {
    def readData(sqlContext: SQLContext, fileType: FileType.Value): List[DataFrame] = {
    //some logic

}
```

I am writing test for the execute function

```
    import com.utils.ReadUtils.readData
    
    class Logs extends Interface with NativeImplicits{
    
    override def execute(sqlContext: SQLContext){
        val inputDFs: List[DataFrame] = readData(sqlContext, FileType.PARQUET)
        //some logic
    }
```

how to mock the readData function to return a dummy value when writing test for execute function? Currently its calling the actual function.

```
test("Log Test") {
val df1 = //some dummy df
val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()
    sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
   
val log = new Logs()
    val mockedReadUtils = mock[ReadUtils.type]
    when(mockedReadUtils.readData(sparkSession.sqlContext,FileType.PARQUET)).thenReturn(df1)
    log.execute(sparkSession.sqlContext)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking scala object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576272/mocking-scala-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is - you can't do it. Objects are basically singletons in scala and you can't mock singletons - that's one of the reasons why they say that you should avoid singletons as much as possible.

You could mock *sqlContext* instead, and all its functions which are called in readData function.

As another approach, you could try to add Dependency Injection with some sort of Cake Pattern - https://medium.com/rahasak/scala-cake-pattern-e0cd894dae4e

```
trait DataReader {
  def readData(sqlContext: SQLContext, fileType: FileType.Value): List[DataFrame]
}

trait RealDataReader {
  def readData(sqlContext: SQLContext, fileType: FileType.Value): List[DataFrame] = {
    // some code
  }
}

trait MockedDataReader {
  def readData(sqlContext: SQLContext, fileType: FileType.Value): List[DataFrame] = {
     // some moking code
  }
}

class Logs extends Interface with NativeImplicits with DataReader {

override def execute(sqlContext: SQLContext){
  val inputDFs: List[DataFrame] = readData(sqlContext, FileType.PARQUET)
    //some logic
  }
}

class RealLogs extends Logs with RealDataReader // that would be the real class

class MockedLogs extends Logs with MockedDataReader // that would be the class for tests
```